# cfoutput not throwing any results

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Hi I have a component that contains getters and setters, which is fed by a structure for session variables.
When I call the component and use `cfoutput` tag for that getter and setter the output is giving gibberish as results.

```
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE@6187548c     cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_FLAGS@7bbfe559 
   cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_FLAGS@7bbfe559 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_RECORD_NUMBER@736a7587 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_RECORD_NUMBER@736a7587 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE@6187548c 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE@6187548c 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_WEIGHT@524a2d43 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETCUSTOMER_WEIGHT@524a2d43 
cffunctions_allDefinedSessnFunct2ecfc3324199482$funcGETVIN@3e1b3ea
```

When I do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the variable values passed, I find them below in the ColdFusion Debugging Information.
I want to get the requisite cfoutput values, which i was getting as desired previously .

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to output the getters?

Answer (score 3):

by all accounts I'd say you're outputting the component itself instead of one of its string properties. Check your output code.

Comment: Yes or the component functions. My guess would be they forgot the "()"  ie Mistakenly used #obj.getVin# instead of #obj.getVin()# . I think that ends up displaying some combination of the internal class name and hash code (?).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this?

```
<cfset allDSF = createObject("component", cfc.allDefinedSessnFunct") />
<cfoutput>#allDSF.getCUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE()#</cfoutput>
```

Some code would help us to help you...